# How to make a loading gif for facebook tab iframe app

Tags: facebook, iframe

Q1. It seems facebook is killing all animated gif's is this true?

If someone has figured out how to display loading gifs on facebook apps, please tell me what the best way to do the following is:

I have a UK-based server serving an iframe in a facebook tab. It takes ages for the page to load because facebook is pulling the page from its servers in US.

My idea is to serve a free-ly hosted, fast loading page that loads the facebook loading gif and loads my iframe from the UK in the background. Once the iframe is loaded, the onload() event will fire and remove the loading gif... pretty standard.

Q2. Will this work?
Q3. If so what free hosted servers are peered with facebook's servers?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Facebook app setting to point to a page on your local servers that loads quickly that will do two things.  Display a GIF, and also redirect to the slower servers using JavaScript. That way the user will see the GIF until the browser can render the new page.  No need to change Facebook or it's servers.  :)